# How to find the rating of facebook Page using C#

Tags: facebook, rating

As per facebook API documentation we can get Facebook Page ratings using  "/{page_id}/ratings". For this we need page access token.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/ratings
How can I get Page Access Token from facebook application.

Please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
/me/accounts
```

endpoint as described here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/accounts/

Be sure to grant the `manage_pages` permission. Try it 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v2.0

Furthermore, I'd recommend to exchange the short-lived token from the last step to a long-lived one (60 days) as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending